# Executing Multiple IT blocks inside a Protractor For loop for web testing

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

We need to use  for loop after login to a web page and perform multiple tests inside the for block on the page. My ideal test scenario should be like the snippet below.  We have a table that have buttons on each of the row, and we will navigate to the next page for that particular button and validate data. currently we plugged all expects and assertions in a single IT block, but that is not a good solution. We need to split the sections of tests in different IT block.

```
require('..\\waitAbsent.js');
require("../node_modules/jasmine-expect/index.js");
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

describe('Student Enrollment Page Content Validation', function() {


beforeAll(function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.get(globalVariables.loginMain);
    globalVariables.Email_Input_box.sendKeys(globalVariables.Demo_User);
    globalVariables.Password_Input_Box.sendKeys(globalVariables.Demo_PWD);
    globalVariables.Submit_Button.click();
    browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(globalVariables.Submit_Button), 25000, 'submit button is not disappearing yet');
});

async function Row_Numbers() {

    const RowCount = (globalVariables.tableData_Dashboard.all(by.tagName("tr")).count()).then(function(RC){

        return RC;

    });

}

for (var i = 1; i<Row_Numbers(); i++){

    function tableData(n){
        var row_1 = globalVariables.tableData_Dashboard.all(by.tagName("tr")).get(n);

        // get cell values
        var cells = row_1.all(by.tagName("td"));

        it ('should return the data fo the first cell', function(){
            var Student_ID = cells.get(0).getText().then(function (SID) {
                console.log(SID);

                return SID;

            });

            expect(Student_ID.toEqual('Something'));
        });

        it ("should show the button in this row", async function(){

            const Button = globalVariables['Edit_Button_' + n];
            // console.log(Button)
            expect(await Button.isDisplayed());
            Button.click();
            // do some thing

        });
    }tableData(i)
}

});
```

When we run the test using this script, we get the following error:

> E/launcher - Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involve
>   s client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643 for details"

How can I use the for loop to achieve our goal?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of comments about this.

Firstly, Your angular error is because the Row_number function you declare is outside of any it block and therefore running before your beforeAll has run.

Next there should be no need for your tableData function as it appears replacing it's parameter n with the i counter from the loop would have the same effect.

Finally if your code needs to go across multiple pages to achieve these tests it will likely be much better to use a data-driven approach and write separate data files for each test. Do the values of these tables row change or would they be consistent?

**Update:**
This approach may look something like this but I have not tested this.

```
beforeAll(function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.get(globalVariables.loginMain);
    globalVariables.Email_Input_box.sendKeys(globalVariables.Demo_User);
    globalVariables.Password_Input_Box.sendKeys(globalVariables.Demo_PWD);
    globalVariables.Submit_Button.click();
    browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(globalVariables.Submit_Button), 25000, 'submit button is not disappearing yet');
});

it('test it', async () => {
    globalVariables.tableData_Dashboard.all(by.tagName("tr")).forEach((row) => {
        var cells = row.all(by.tagName("td"));

        var Student_ID = cells.get(0).getText().then(function (SID) {
            console.log(SID);
            return SID;
        });

        expect(Student_ID.toEqual('Something'), 'should return the data fo the first cell');

        const Button = globalVariables['Edit_Button_' + n];
        // console.log(Button)
        expect(Button.isDisplayed(), 'should show the button in this row').toBe(true);
        Button.click();
        // do some thing

    });
})
```

Comment: The table data is dynamic .. they are rendered by API calls.

Comment: Is it correct to say that your test should verify a particular student id goes to a particular page and contains information about that student? and you want to do that for each row in the table

Comment: Yes, exactly. On each students page there are multiple sections that we need to test

Comment: The challenge you will face with this is that protractor will process your code to determine how many it blocks need to be executed before any code is launched. You are trying to loop through the number of rows but I do not know of a way to get this information before the spec if evaluated. I can't see a way to achieve this using multiple its. If you can figure out a way to make an api call to what is populating the data in the onPrepare and get a count from that you could set it as a global variable

Comment: I should also mentioned that you have the ability to add a second parameter to your expects which is a string explaining the purpose of your test. (method) jasmine.Matchers<number>.toBeLessThanOrEqual(expected: number, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean. This could allows you to know which expect has failed if you are using multiple.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use this in the script

Comment: Cool, I updated the answer with some potential code that may help but I have not tested it out